# Normal distribution in an interval

Tags: integration, statistics, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

I am interested in the cumulative function of the normal distribution, because I want to get the distribution which has the support $[0,2\pi]$, and it looks like a normal distribution. Therefore, if I get the closed form of $F(2\pi)$ and $F(0)$, I can get the new distribution which has the pdf:
$$\frac1{F(2\pi) -F(0)}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp{(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})},~x\in[0,2\pi]$$

For example, can we calculate the following integral:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp{(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})}$$

Is there exists any method which can be used to get the closed form of it. Or can we get any similar distribution?

Comment: Where did you get stuck?  Please show us what work you've done.  Or provide us with information about the class or course or text you are studying for/from, and some some definitions you've been taught, like "normal distribution", and then "cumulative normal distribution."  If you don't know those definitions and so can't address those definitions in your post, search for them in your notes and/or in your text, and/or on-line.  Please improve your post (edit it) by including your efforts and/or the definitions you're working with.

Comment: There exists no closed form. But you can calculate it numerically in a few step since $2\pi$ is not far away from $0$

Comment: It doesn´t help to edit you question several times without new information. You have to give a reply to the ansawer or the comments. Are you interested in a numerical method or not?

Comment: Yes. I think the only way to get the answer is by some numerical methods. My goal is to find a distribution which looks like the normal distribution but has the support on a interval.

Comment: @coolcat You can look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/871800/144421) for a nice and easy approximation (similar distribution). I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no closed-form version of it, because the Gaussian does not have an elementary antiderivative. You use tables, or you compute it numerically.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the mostly used CDF in this case is $1-Q(\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$ where $Q(.)$ denotes the $Q$ function and has no close form. You can also refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function